# Get file path from input in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hvae input file like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtPath" placeholder="No file selected" />
<input id="btnBrowse" type="button"  value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<input type="file" id="loadFile" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" />
```

And I want to alert the selected path, I tried like:

```
document.getElementById("loadFile").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("txtPath");
  let files = event.target.files;
alert(files);
},false);
```

But this doesn't work, the error:

> Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: Explain in detail *this doesn't work*

Comment: Can give a more precise description, what does not work?

Comment: Your file picker has two id attributes defined. `id="loadFile"` and `id="file"`. I suspect this is causing `onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" ` to fail.

Comment: @Kei you are right! **Codey** see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/calepsol/efdmxnkr/24/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` for input:

> *id="loadFile"* style="display:none;" *id="file"*

```
<input type="text" id="txtPath" placeholder="No file selected" />
<input id="btnBrowse" type="button"  value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" />
```

World example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/calepsol/efdmxnkr/26/)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't alert the file name, have you tested the jsFiddle link?

Comment: For alert file name `{
  let output = document.getElementById("txtPath");
  let files = event.target.files;
 alert(files[0].name)
},false);`